# PHP while loop returning only one row when SUM added to multiple JOIN query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT a.sender_id,
                    a.recipient_id,
                    a.form_id, due_date,
                    a.completed,
                    f.name,
                    p.priority,
                    u.first_name,
                    u.last_name,
                    SUM(a.completed) as completed_sum
                    FROM form_assignments a
                    JOIN forms f ON (form_id = f.id)
                    JOIN users u ON (sender_id = u.id)
                    JOIN priorities p ON (priority_id = p.id)
                    WHERE recipient_id = '{$_SESSION['user_id']}'
                    ORDER BY due_date ASC";
```

And a while loop like this:

```
$assignment_count = (mysqli_num_rows($result));
$assignments_row = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $sender = $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'];
      $form_id = $row['form_id'];
      $form_name = $row['name'];
      $priority = $row['priority'];
      $due_date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($row['due_date']));
      $completed = $row['completed'];
      $not_done = $assignment_count - $row['completed_sum'];
    }
```

And it's only returning one row. It seems  my `SUM(a.completed) as completed_sum` is causing the issues because the query worked fine before I added it, but I want to add up all the values in `completed` to use in my `$not_done` variable.

Can anyone help clarify what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have no `GROUP BY` clause in the query. So you're summing everything into one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an aggregate function like `SUM`, all the results will be aggregated into one row unless you use a `GROUP BY` clause to segregate them. But it looks to me like you don't need a `SUM` in the first place. Your loop is subtracting this value from a total, so you just need the value from each row -- when you subtract them all you'll have subtracted the total. So just select `a.completed` rather than `SUM(a.completed)`.

For `$not_done`, you need to initialize it before the loop:

```
$not_done = $assignment_count;
```

Then during the loop you should do a running subtraction:

```
$not_done -= $row['completed'];
```

Comment: This seems like a better solution for what I'm after, but after changing it I now have all my rows back but `$not_done` is still equal to `$assignment_count` instead of `$assignment_count - $completed;`

Comment: You're not subtracting from the current value of `$not_done`, you're subtracting from `$assignment_count` each time. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
SELECT 
           a.sender_id,
           a.recipient_id,
           a.form_id,
           a.due_date,
           a.completed,
           f.name,
           p.priority,
           u.first_name,
           u.last_name,
           b.completed as completed_sum
      FROM
           form_assignments AS a
           LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT form_id,SUM(completed) FROM form_assignments GROUP BY form_id
           ) AS b ON (a.form_id = b.form_id)
           LEFT JOIN forms AS f ON (form_id = f.id)
           LEFT JOIN users AS u ON (sender_id = u.id)
           LEFT JOIN priorities AS p ON (priority_id = p.id)
      WHERE
           recipient_id = '{$_SESSION['user_id']}'
      ORDER BY due_date ASC
```